# Excel - convert text to formula and get value

Tags: excel

I've got my data like this:

```
      A   |     B     
1 |   10  |  "A1+A2"
2 |   5   |  "=A1+A2" 
3 |       |           
4 |  here |
```

Now what I want, is in cell `A4` to have something (a formula or whatever) that automatically makes me get the result of `B1` or `B2`, whichever is the easiest to work with.

I tried using `=INDIRECT`, but couldn't get that to work, and I'm **not able** to use VBA (Since I need to import the file elsewhere and it doesn't accept .xlsm files. I know I can have a .xlsm file and save it as .xls and import that, but I'm just curious if there's another way)

Is there a way to do this **without** VBA?

Comment: ` whichever is the easiest to work with` ... can you elaborate on what this means?

Comment: If there's one formula in which the first will work, but you need three nested formulas to make the second one work, I'd name the first one 'easier to work with'

Comment: Are you always summing the data or will the formulas become more complicated?

Comment: Formulas become more complicated. One of the easier ones looks like `=C15+(C14*(C12-C13)*(244/12))`

Comment: Then there is no way without vba

Comment: One idea is to do it backwards, and put the formula in the cell in which you want the answer, and use FORMULATEXT() in the other to display the formula.